# The value specified in the URL Key field would generate a URL that already exists

Tags: magento2, category, url-rewrite

I created category with url key name is "xxxxx". I have changed that category url key to "YYYYY". INow i dont like that url key for that category. Again i changed the url key to "xxxxx". It throws "The value specified in the URL Key field would generate a URL that already exists.

Please help me to change the old url key."

Comment: the issue is comming from url_rewrite table, please check with it.

Answer (score -2):

Manually delete last entry of 'xxxxx' from

```
 Marketing -> URL Rewrite
```

It will solve the problem.